# node.js: get variable's name

Tags: node.js

```
let f = function(list) //'list' is an array [o1, o2, etc.]
{
  list.forEach(function(e) 
  {
    console.log('name ', ??);     
  };
};
```

just wonder how to get current elm's name to have output like that:
o1
o2

thnx

p.s. toString() puts [object Object]

Comment: You don't, nor should you ever need to. Your array contains vales and references, not variable names.

Comment: it is nice, but you never know what you might need to) at least, it may be used for debugging purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing forEach here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Doing a forEach you get access (in the callback) to three pieces of information. The currentValue, the index and the whole array. I'm unsure exactly of what you are looking for, but given that it is an array you really only have 2 key pieces, the index and the value.

Changing your code up you can output both of those pieces of data like this:

```
let f = function(list) { //'list' is an array [o1, o2, etc.]
    list.forEach(function(val, ind) {
        console.log('value at index(%d): %o', ind, val)
     })
}
```

Note that I use `%o` for the value as it is the best catch-all for handling multiple different types of objects when using console.

Comment: nice - it is appropriate method! it is useful for logging - just imagine - you log a bunch or properties of each element in list - thnx)

Comment: Note that if you really are only using this for logging you might as well just log the whole array without resorting to the forEach. Just try:

    console.log("full array: %o", list)

Comment: I get you. But for my case - it is more comfortable to have separate logging for each element